# How to split the string and save the last word in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a string like this : abc0__remote_contr_major_abc__remote_hjk_klo_hcf_uio__apple_b_0_t_boo_dfs

I need to extract apple followed by everything until t_ and use that as a variable.

for example; if the string goes through the code, I am expecting apple_b_0_t as my output. I tried split and lindex but didnt work out.

```
set s "abc0__remote_contr_major_abc__remote_hjk_klo_hcf_uio__apple_b_0_t_boo_dfs"
set prefix [split $s "__"]
set c [lindex $prefix 4]
```

So ended up doing this and it worked but I am wondering if there is a easier/generic solution

```
set prefix [join [lrange [split $tile_dfx_fclk "__"] 12 15] _]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex:

```
set s abc0__remote_contr_major_abc__remote_hjk_klo_hcf_uio__apple_b_0_t_boo_dfS
regexp {.*__(.*t)_.*} $s _ t
puts $t                                    ;# => apple_b_0_t
```

The problem with `split $s "__"` is that the 2nd argument to split is not a substring: it's a **set** of characters, so it's just the same as `split $s "_"`

tcllib has a `textutil::split` package containing a `splitx` proc that splits a string on a *regular expression*

```
package require textutil::split
namespace import textutil::split::splitx
set last [lindex [splitx $s "__"] end]     ;# => apple_b_0_t_boo_dfS
# and then
set wanted [regsub {[^t]*$} $last ""]      ;# => apple_b_0_t
```

Another approach is to find the last place that `__` occurs in the string:

```
set idx [string last "__" $s]              ;# => 52
# and then
set last [string range $s $idx+2 end]      ;# => apple_b_0_t_boo_dfS
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try the regexp.

Comment: As for the last variant, I would also look for the end marker `set end [string last "_t" $s]` and then: `string range $s $idx+2 $end+1`. This will yield `apple_b_0_t`, as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done:

```
set s "abc0__remote_contr_major_abc__remote_hjk_klo_hcf_uio__apple_b_0_t_boo_dfs"
set c [string range $s [string first "apple_" $s] [string last "t_" $s]]
puts $c
-> apple_b_0_t
```